# Return a remote PDF as application/pdf in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, spring-dsl

I need to return a remote PDF file as `application/pdf`. In a classic WAR, I'd build a [servlet](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) that retrieves the remote PDF as [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and returns the same PDF as [OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html), is possible to do so in [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/)? What is the best practice?

I saw [camel-servlet](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) but I didn't understand the way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution: defining the rest service as follows (REST DSL)

```
<rest path="/">
    <get consumes="application/json"
        outType="java.io.InputStream"
        produces="application/pdf" uri="/provarest">
        <to uri="direct:provaRest"/>
    </get>
</rest>
```

I'm able to return the PDF with this route

```
<route id="route6">
    <from id="_from1Route6" uri="direct:provaRest"/>
    <to id="_toProvaRest" uri="provaRestProcessorId"/>
</route>
```

where provaRestProcessorId is a processor with this method

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\somepath\\Prova.pdf"));
    exchange.getOut().setBody(is);
}
```